# Angular Form validation with slides

Tags: angularjs

I'am new to angular, I have an angular form which is having 4 slides. In my form I'm providing validations in such a way only if the validation 1st slide is passing the validation step, it should allow me to move to the 2nd slide.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-hide="slide === 1" ng-click="back()">{{button1}}</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-hide="slide === 4" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="ok()">{{button2}}</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">{{button3}}</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ac.theForm()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">SUBMIT</button>
```

I want to provide that validation to  button2

Comment: are you looking for something like http://angularjs.io/how-to-create-a-custom-input-validator-with-angularjs/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a form which you want validating in sections you should use subforms to validate each of those sections independently.  This can be achieved with ng-form.  The whole form must still be wrapped in form tags to allow standard form functionality like submit.  Here is an example, you just need to put each ng-form on its own slide:

```
  <ng-form name="slide1">
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="val1">
    <button ng-disabled="slide1.$invalid">Next</button>
  </ng-form>
  <hr>
  <ng-form name="slide2">
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="val2">
    <button ng-disabled="slide2.$invalid">Next</button>
  </ng-form>
  <hr>
  <ng-form name="slide3">
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="val3">
    <button ng-disabled="slide3.$invalid">Next</button>
  </ng-form>
  <hr>
  <button ng-click="submitForm" ng-disabled="parentForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/9Gvg2B3MOeiW2P1iEdQ4?p=preview

Comment: thanks it worked , I was using a common button for all the slides... but to get the work done I changed it according to ur code